# Garry's Mod Question shows up twice in question list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I do not know if this is a bug but Garry's Mod Question shows up twice in question list. Here is a screen cap.

[image: Garry's Mod multiple Questions]

Umm is this normal? If so then please just ask me to go away. :-)

Comment: Link to the page? What question list?

Comment: Okay, then that does seem like something that _shouldn't_ happen. (If you leave the current answer as accepted, the team won't look at this question.)

Comment: A link would help.

Comment: Odd, might indeed be a bug then.

Comment: Mega speculation time: if for any reason the SE tag engine fails to load questions by tag the query is sent to elastic search instead, but without limitation to just questions

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly normal. The first result is the answer to the question, which is the second result. (See the "A:" and "Q:" prefixes.) If you only want to see one, not the other, use `is:answer` or `is:question` in the search.